# Create a block variation of list elements

Tags: block-editor

I would like to create a variation of a block that has a parent ul or ol element on it, depending on the block you click.

Is it possible to use [Block Variations](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/) to change the parent html element? For example, can we apply the following concept in code, or is this a no-go? ...

`index.js`

```js
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {

  //...other code here...
    
    edit: Edit,
    save,
    variations: [
      {
        name: 'blachawk-blocks/list-block-ordered',
        title: __( 'An ordered block' ),
        icon: 'list-view',
          attributes: {
            listOrdered: true,
          },
        },
      ],
  } );
```

`edit.js`

```js
    
    export default function Edit( props ) {

    //...other innerBlocksProps code here...

    //the focus of my question :
    const { attributes } = props;
    const { listOrdered } = attributes; 

    return listOrdered ? (
        <ol { ...innerBlocksProps } />
     ) : (
        <ul { ...innerBlocksProps } />
    );
```

Obviously the code above is wrong.  But I am trying to make an effort to learn here.  Is this process possible?

If I am on the right track, how far off am I? So far when I run this in the browser, it gives me `ul` for both block types, from my blocks list panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am working with block attributes, I had to also define my attribute within my block.json file...

`block.json`

```json
    "attributes": {
        "listOrdered": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        }
```

Now with that set in place, I can now run `npm start`, and see my block variant working well in wp-admin edit page. It allows me a pick either an ordered or unordered list version of my block.

[image]

Since my custom block also includes the use of innerBlocks, my final variation in index.js looked something like this...

```js
    variations: [
        {
            name: 'blachawk-blocks/list-block-ordered',
            title: __( 'List Block Ordered' ),
            icon: {
                src: 'list-view',
                background: '#4682b4',
                foreground: '#fff',
            },
            keywords: [ 'blachawk', 'lists', 'list', 'unordered', 'item' ],
            attributes: {
                listOrdered: true,
            },
            innerBlocks: [ [ 'blachawk-blocks/list-block-item' ] ],
        },
    ],
```

Finally, I also made sure the `registerBlockType()` for my list-block-item, has two parents in its own index.js file like so...

```js
registerBlockType( 'blachawk-blocks/list-block-item', {

 //...code

    //lets make sure each li item is associated to either the ul or ol variation...
    parent: [
        'blachawk-blocks/list-block',
        'blachawk-blocks/list-block-unordered',
    ],

  //...more code
}
```